# I cant gem install cocoapods, its crash

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, cocoapods

When I install cocoapods in terminal, it shows me error "wrong number of arguments". I don't know how to resolve this error, please help me.

Error message:

> /Users/RaInVis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/path_support.rb:25:in
>   `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
>   (ArgumentError)

Comment: Could you provide the command you executed to install cocoapods? Or any other useful information.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to completely uninstall ruby from your mac. For this open terminal and run the following command if you have already installed Homebrew on your mac:

**brew uninstall ruby**

If you don't have Homebrew installed on your mac already then you can follow the [link](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan).

Now, you can use rbenv tool to install latest version of ruby, to do this run:

**brew install rbenv ruby-build**

and run following command to install ruby:

**rbenv install 2.3.1**

**rbenv global 2.3.1**

**ruby -v**

and, now your **gem install cocoapods** command will install cocoapods on your mac.

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues using Ruby 2.3 when installing cocoapods. It worked well with Ruby 2.2.2 though. Maybe you can switch versions?